# Angularjs - returning data from a ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fetch

I'm trying to fetch some data from my database and it works fine in my ng-option, but I can't grab the output and show it to the user with the selectCenter.land

This is my ng-option

```
            <select
            ng-model="selectCenter"
            ng-options="center.center_navn for center in centre | filter:searchCentre"
            ng-change="findCenter(114)"
            multiple class="form-control input-lg">
        </select>
        You have chosen:
        {{ selectCenter }}
```

my output in the console looks fine like this: [Object, Object, Object, Object] where I have

[0]
[1] etc.

and on the "you have Chosen" it shows

```
 [{"id":"122","shopID":"200","land":"denmark"}]
```

Can some one see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your piece of code:

1. correct option name for *ngOptions*. I didn't see `center_navn` is an attribute of your `center` object.
2. working filter.

Please provide more details about what the scope variable `centre` is.

Here's working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q8jhdJltlh14oBBLeHJ9?p=preview